# How to start the DataBase design for a web project?

Tags: php, database-design

I plan to develop a web directory system.(php used)

But i don't know how to start the Data Base design.

Are there any good books/tutorials about it? Thank you.

Comment: Question is too broad and does not provide enough information about the requirements or desired functionality of the project or the database used. If you have no clue about DB Design, start at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design or search the terms http://www.google.de/search?q=database+design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions you should ask yourself (or the product owner) are:

- What entities are at the heart of
  your application?
- How are they
  linked to each other?

My guess: Web directory system has got:

- Entries
- Categories
- Tags
- Users

Now take it further.. how are these related to each other?

- Entries belong to categories
- Tags are associated with entries
- Entries are submitted by users

And another step..

- Entries have titles, descriptions, images, links, contact info
- Users have usernames, emails, passwords

.. and so on